# Smoothing extremal points in handwritten digits

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I am trying to recognize hand written digits. Say that I have the following image:

[image: Original]

My target is to smooth the extremal features of the contours, and keep only the shape of the white trace like below:

[image: mod]

I first applied `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV` to remove the noise.

[image: TBI]

Now I tried applying `cv2.erode()` with `np.ones((5,5))` as the kernel, but the resulting figure still had the extremal points.

[image: eroded]

I think applying `cv2.findContours()` may help to get the desired shape, but I am going to end up with two contours, one for the inner and another for the outer part. Any ideas will be much appreciated!

Edit:
Thanks to @stateMachine, I managed to get a skeleton of the digit. I applied `cv2.ximgproc.thinning()`, followed by `cv2.GaussianBlur()` and `cv2.MORPH_CLOSE`. If the extremal points of this image can be smoothened a bit then it would be perfect. I am still open to any ideas :)

[image: skel]

Comment: You can try Gaussian smoothing followed by threshold

Answer (score 5):

Maybe what you are looking for is the shape's **skeleton**. The skeleton is part of OpenCV's extended image processing module (`pip install opencv-contrib-python`). You can compute the skeleton of your image like this:

```
# Imports:
import cv2

# Image path
path = "D://opencvImages//"
fileName = "OKwfZ.png"

# Reading an image in default mode:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path + fileName)

# To Grayscale:
grayscaleImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Compute the skeleton:
skeleton = cv2.ximgproc.thinning(grayscaleImage, None, 1)

cv2.imshow("Skeleton", skeleton)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the result:

[image]

The skeleton normalizes the thickness of the image to `1 pixel`. If you need a thicker line you can apply some `dilations`.